# ¿Como puedo hacer para que un subproceso tome un valor y lo ejecute en un comando externo?

Tags: python

He estado leyendo la documentación de subprocesos  en python y no le entiendo a como pasar los parámetros a un comando externo.
El comando que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
cellranger testrun --id=tiny
```

Y quiero remplazar el valor "id"  por uno que el usuario ingrese y se ejecute cuando es presionado un botón.

De antemano muchas por su atención

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para ejecutar un subproceso tienes que construir una lista que tenga el nombre del ejecutable y sus parametros.

Por ejemplo, si deseo reproducir un video a pantalla completa con `mplayer`, escribiría esto en la línea de comandos:

```
mplayer -fs /videos/spacex.mpg
```

Si quiero ejecutarlo con `subprocess`, primero construyo la lista

```
mplayerCall = ['mplayer', '/videos/spacex.mpg', "-fs"]
```

y luego la ejecuto:

```
resultado = subprocess.check_output(mplayerCall, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, start_new_session=True).decode('utf-8')
```

`check_output` me retorna bytes, los que convierto a una cadena usando `decode`.

Los parámetros `stdin, stdout, stderr` dicen a donde redirigir la entrada, salida y error estándar.

En tu caso, la lista sería:

```
llamada = ['cellranger',  'testrun', f'--{id}=tiny']
```

donde usamos f-strings para formatear el parámetro `--id=tiny` con el valor ingresado por el usuario.